# How to Find the SCSS Index of the element in the list?

Tags: html, css, web, sass, frontend

Iam working on SCSS Loops and got stuck with a problem. The Problem is consider a list of colors.

```
$colors:'red','green','red','blue';

@each $color in $colors{
  $i:index($colors,$color);
  .cube:nth-child(#{$i}){
    background:$color;
  };
}
```

The Output of the above program is

```
.cube:nth-child(1) {
  background: "red";
}

.cube:nth-child(2) {
  background: "green";
}

.cube:nth-child(1) { // issue here unable to get index value 3
  background: "red"; 
}

.cube:nth-child(4) {
  background: "blue";
}
```

I am unable to get the index value 3. Can Someone help me to solve this issue.
My question is

1. how to get the index value of 3?
2. Is it possible to get the index using each? if "YES" how?
3. If not what's the alternative way?

Comment: each loop with index:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146706/each-loop-with-index

Comment: do you want that the color of `cube` will be as colors list (in same index)?

Comment: yes, i need to get the index value of 3 using a loop.

Comment: OK but in index=1 color will be red in 2 green...?

Comment: i am using the hard coded value for my background color. I just want the index value. for now leave about the background color.

Comment: @לבנימלכה, updated the code. please check

Comment: what about do it as it:https://jsfiddle.net/j0dt62hz/

Comment: no not working 
https://www.sassmeister.com
check your code here.

Comment: why not? I wrap the divs and use `nth` to wrap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
$colors:'red','green','red','blue';

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
  $color: nth($colors, $i);
  .cube:nth-child(#{$i}){
    background:$color;
  };
}
```

Your's fails cause `index($colors,$color)` will return always the first position of the element: Read ->http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#index-instance_method