# How to have key, value, and index number in a loop from a Sass map?

Tags: sass

I am having issues figuring out how to get all three variables at once.

I have a map `$breakpoints`:

```
$breakpoints: (
  'large': 1200px,
  'medium': 1024px,
  'tablet': 768px,
  'mini': 480px
) !default;
```

And a loop that starts like this with the `index()` function:

```
  @each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
    $i: index($breakpoints, $key);

}
```

Or tried

```
@each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
  $i: index($breakpoints, ($key: $value));
}
```

```
@each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
  $i: index($breakpoints, $value);
}
```

Using only value, not key (not working): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24243797/6368685

Nothing is working. It is always null. The `index()` function appears to be the ticket except it is only for lists it appears.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53155930/6368685

I also looked at maybe instead of `@each` get all three via a `@for` loop. But no answers could I find getting all three values. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach =>

```
$breakpoints: (
  "large": 1200px,
  'medium': 1024px,
  'tablet': 768px,
  'mini': 480px
) !default;

@each $key, $value in $breakpoints{
  $i: index($breakpoints, $key $value);
  .test {
      margin: #{$i}rem;
  }
}
```

I tested it on this [sass-online-compiler](https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/), and it works just fine.

[gulp-boilerplate](https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate)